# Calling multiple constructors - Only goes to the same one?

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

I'm new to Java and I can't figure this out.  I've tried passing values in the arguments of my objects, but it only wants to go to the constructor with no parameters.  The other 2 have multiple parameters but it doesn't notice it?  Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:

```
    Car vehicle1 = new Car();
    Car vehicle2 = new Car();
    Car vehicle3 = new Car();

public Car() {

    private int numberOfCars;

    private String company;
    private String modelName;
    private String modelYear;
    private double hp;
    private int doors;
    private String gears;
    private String color;
    private boolean racingCar;
    private double price;

        numberOfCars = -1;
        company = "***EMPTY***";
        modelName = "***EMPTY***";
        modelYear = "***EMPTY***";
        hp = -1;
        doors = -1;
        gears = "***EMPTY***";
        color = "***EMPTY***";
        racingCar = false;
        price = -1;
    }
    public Car(String companyName, String modelNa, String modelYe){

        numberOfCars = -1;
        company = companyName;
        modelName = modelNa;
        modelYear = modelYe;
        hp = -1;
        doors = -1;
        gears = "***EMPTY***";
        color = "***EMPTY***";
        racingCar = false;
        price = -1;
    }
    public Car(int carAmount, String companyTitle, String modelTitle, String modelBirth, double horsePower, int door, String gearType, String colors, boolean raceCar, double prices){

        numberOfCars = carAmount;
        company = companyTitle;
        modelName = modelTitle;
        modelYear = modelBirth;
        hp = horsePower;
        doors = door;
        gears = gearType;
        color = colors;
        racingCar = raceCar;
        price = prices;
    }
```

Comment: are you missing a few lines of code? Such as the no-arg constructor?

Comment: Your code is incomplete: you didn't include the line that has the constructor with no arguments. Also, can you add *how* you are trying to invoke the other constructors? The declarations look fine so it is probably related to how you invoke them.

Answer (score 1):

In order to call the other constructors, you need to specify parameters when you build your object:

```
Car vehicle1 = new Car();
Car vehicle2 = new Car("companyName", "modelNa", "modelYe");
Car vehicle3 = new Car(2, "companyTitle", "modelTitle", "modelBirth", 5.2, 4, "gearType", "colors", false, 1600);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is complete coding for the problem you are facing

---

```
class Car
{
  String company;
  String modelName;
  String modelYear;
  double hp;
  int doors;
  String gears;
  String color;
  boolean racingCar;
  double price;
  int numberOfCars;



  public Car() {

    numberOfCars = 1;
    company = "BMW";
    modelName = "BMW M3 DTM";
    modelYear = "2012";
    hp = 500;
    doors = 2;
    gears = "Clutch";
    color = "Black";
    racingCar =true;
    price = -1;
   }

 public Car(String companyName, String modelNa, String modelYe){

    numberOfCars = 1;
    company = companyName;
    modelName = modelNa;
    modelYear = modelYe;
    hp = 500;
    doors = 2;
    gears = "Clutch";
    color = "White";
    racingCar = true;
    price = 100000;

}
public Car(int carAmount, String companyTitle, String modelTitle, String modelBirth, double horsePower, int door, String gearType, String colors, boolean raceCar, double prices){

    numberOfCars = carAmount;
    company = companyTitle;
    modelName = modelTitle;
    modelYear = modelBirth;
    hp = horsePower;
    doors = door;
    gears = gearType;
    color = colors;
    racingCar = raceCar;
    price = prices;

}

public static void main(String args[]) 
 {
Car vehicle1 = new Car();
Car vehicle2 = new Car("BMW", "BMW M3 DTM", "2012");
Car vehicle3 = new Car(1, "BMW", "BMW M3 DTM", "2012", 500, 2, "Clutch", "White", true, 5000000);
}
}
```

---

There are some basic facts you should understand before you work with constructors

- **No Parameter-** Compiler will search for Method/Constructor with no parameter
- **With Parameter-** Compiler will search for Method/Constructor with parameter you specify while calling.
- Also **Type** & **Number** of parameters matters

Google it, you will find the theories!

Answer (score 0):

Like Guillaume said, the parameterized constructor needs to invoked using the arguments when you instantiate you object. You can see this example

http://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/parameterized-constructor-in-java-example/

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you write a class and do not include any constructor, Java provides automatically for you a default constructor (one without parameters),and the virtual machine initializes all instance variables of the class (if there are any) with some default values (0, null, or false). If you write a constructor, however, with some parameters, and you don't write any default constructor, then Java does not provide a default constructor.
[see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)
which indicates the code you pasted here may miss a no-arg constructor?

And notice that to call the constructor with parameters, you need to provides parameters when you instantiate you object.